# Is it possible to set session cookie path in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, cookies, jetty, session-cookies, jetty-9

I'm looking for something that can be done like this setting in Tomcat:

```
<Context ... sessionCookiePath="/" > ... </Context>
```

Comment: Depends on how you are setting cookies in the first place.  How are you currently setting the session cookie?

Comment: I'm not doing anything specific other than extending the max age of the cookie. By default it creates a new session cookie for every context path and I want that to change.

Answer (score -1):

You can persist session information in database like Datastore and use Memcache to get the session/user information faster. Take a look at the web application architecture - https://cloud.google.com/solutions/architecture/webapp